# Adding Semicolon CSS discrupts code

Tags: html, css

I am new in learning PHP/CSS and I'm confused:

I have created this CSS code to divide my website into divisions.
When I use the code like this, there is no problem:

```
#main {
    float:left
    min-height:500px
    min-width:350px
}
```

but using the code below, with the semicolons, it is creating a problem.

```
#main {
    float:left;
    min-height:500px;
    min-width:350px;
}
```

I am using the following code to display a simple line of text

```
<div id="main">
    <p style=text-align:center>
        This website is, and will be for a significant period, <b>under construction.</b></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

When I am using the semicolons, the text won't align to the center, but without the semicolons it will. So now I am confused, I thought you always had to add semicolons at the end of each CSS row? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you have a `<\a>` at the end of the sentence? That will cause problems too.

Comment: On the version without semi-colons the entire block of CSS declarations is ignored because not a single line of it is valid CSS

Comment: You can, however, omit the semicolon after the last rule, just before the closing parenthesis :-)

Comment: @axiac Don't confuse him anymore. :D

Comment: thats because I deleted the actual hypelink but forgot the closing tag!

Comment: @Mark: ignore my previous comment. Always put a semicolon after each CSS rule and you are safe. This is how I do too because it makes addition and deletion of rules easier.

Answer (score 6):

it's the other way around... your code IS working with the semicolons, and it isn't without...

I added a border to make it more clear, in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w1as5t1g/) the semicolons aren't there, in [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/w1as5t1g/1/) they are. You'll see the black border in the second example

This was added:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your first block you aren't actually getting ANY css styling. You are getting the INLINE styling of

`<p style=text-align:center>`

In your second block you are actually setting styling, it's just not doing what you think it's suppose to do.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you out... [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvz55cgb/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Your page title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #main {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <p>This website is, and will be for a significant period, <strong>under construction.</strong></p>
</div>

<div id="another-example" style="text-align:center;">
    <p>Hello centered inline text.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```